# how to use classes to refer to the correct element in jquery

Tags: javascript, html, class

I have cards displayed on the website. I want to display a label on whichever card I am currently hovering on.

main.js

```
 $('.card').on("mouseover", function () {
  $('.ui.right.corner.label').show();
 });
 $('.card').on("mouseout", function () {
  $('.ui.right.corner.label').hide();
 });
```

This appeared to work fine until I realised that specific card's label is shown every time I hover on ANY of the cards.

Index.php

```
<!--first card-->
<div class="card" onclick="window.location='product.php';">

 <img src="img/test1.jpg" class="image">
 <a class="ui right corner label">
   <i class="heart icon"></i>
 </a>
</div>

<!--second card-->
<div class="card" onclick="window.location='product.php';">

 <img src="img/test2.jpg" class="image">
 <a class="ui right corner label">
   <i class="heart icon"></i>
 </a>
</div>

<!--third card-->
<div class="card" onclick="window.location='product.php';">

 <img src="img/test3.jpg" class="image">
 <a class="ui right corner label">
   <i class="heart icon"></i>
 </a>
</div>
```

I have currently fixed the child element problem by using Rajaprabhu's answer. However, the label is now appearing on the website by default. I am using `.hide` to hide them but is there a better way to not show the label when website is loaded?

Comment: You can use 

 $('.card').on("mouseover", function () {
  $(this).closest('.ui.right.corner.label').show();
 });
 $('.card').on("mouseout", function () {
  $(this).closest('.ui.right.corner.label').hide();
 });

Comment: @Allloush Hi thanks for your answer! Please see below for Children, that worked nicely too :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is because you are showing and hiding all the elements with that particular class. Try this method.

```
 $('.card').on("mouseover", function () {
  $(this).children("a").show();
 });
 $('.card').on("mouseout", function () {
  $(this).children("a").hide();
 });
```

Comment: Great answer! Children works elegantly! However when I refresh the page the label is there by default. Why is it so? Is there a way to make it show only when I hover? It'll be great if you can help thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the `this` reference inside of those event handlers,

```
$('.card').on("mouseover", function () {
   $('.ui.right.corner.label', this).show();
});

$('.card').on("mouseout", function () {
  $('.ui.right.corner.label', this).hide();
});
```